# jspdf multiple page cut the pdf bottom line text in half

Tags: jspdf, html2pdf

hello i am trying to generate multiple page dynamic pdf using html in my react js app. i got all the things right in pdf but the last line text of pages cuts if we set the dynamic pixels for html element it also cut table inside the html sometimes. here is my code

```
  var pdf  = new jsPDF({
                        orientation: "portrait", // landscape or portrait
                        unit: "mm",
                        format: "a4"//[250,250],
                          
                        }
                        )

                        let pageHeight=pdf.internal.pageSize.height
                   
                          pdf.html(html_element, {
                          callback: function (doc) {
                            doc.save();
                          },
                          x: 15,
                          autoPaging: "slice",
                          y: 15,
                          width: 170, //target width in the PDF document
                          windowWidth: 650 ,
                          margin:[10,7,10,7],
                          
                       });
```

please help me with this

i have also tried jsdpf html2 convas examples but it did not give bottom margin in pages